# MapView overlay item needs to be a link to a webview

Tags: java, android, webview, overlayitem

So I have a Map that displays markers for all my friends based their coordinates.  Right now when you click a marker it pops up an overlay and gives their details.  What I need to figure out is how to have that overlay include a clickable link that will forward them to my webview.

The current code for plotting my coordinates:

```
        fID = Integer.toString(aFriendid[i]);

        GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint((int)(aLongitude[i] * 1E6), 
                (int)(aLatitude[i] * 1E6));
        OverlayItem overlayitem = new OverlayItem(point, "Friend: ", fID);

        itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem);
        mapOverlays.add(itemizedoverlay);
```

The above gets looped through n times.  The fID is the value I need to append to the forwarded web address.

So the desired effect is in that overlay theres a link "click to view friend details" and that opens my webview with the address: "example.com/fid?=fID".

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the same issues: follow these istruction, particullary, download the source code who Mark linked inside the post.

http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/58226b283b685231/9bc640eab739aadf?lnk=gst&q=pedr0+balloon#9bc640eab739aadf